# How to keep format in html text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm have an application like a webchat, and i'm trying to format a text to a html text. For example:

Text:

```
"<b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit.\n\n Quisque maximus venenatis.</b>"
```

So to convert it to an html text, I'm using the ruby *simple_format* from *ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper*, but it's not keeping the bold formatation like following:

```
"<p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit.</p>\n\n <p>Quisque maximus venenatis.</b></p>"
```

when actually it should be shown as follows

```
"<p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit.</b></p>\n\n <p><b>Quisque maximus venenatis.</b></p>"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please share code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If you apply this code:

```
- html = "<b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit.\n\n Quisque maximus venenatis.</b>"

= simple_format(simple)
```

it will produce such HTML:

```
<p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit.</p>

<p> Quisque maximus venenatis.</b></p>
```

And it keeps bold format for both lines in modern browsers even though it is invalid HTML code. However, it may not work correctly in some browsers

Another option -- use CSS

```
.wrap-lines {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

And then apply this rule to some container

```
- html = "<b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit.\n\n Quisque maximus venenatis.</b>"

.wrap-lines
  == html
```

[`white-space: pre-line;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#pre-line) breaks lines at newline characters, at `<br>` (white space are collapsed)

Comment: The HTML produced by your example has an invalid nesting. The `b` opened after the `p` must be closed before the `p` is closed. While that might work in some browsers, it might break in others that try to auto-correct invalid HTML while parsing.